# Using AS3WavSound to play WAV - cannot stop instantly

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I'm using the AS3WavSound (http://code.google.com/p/as3wavsound/) class to playback externally loaded wavs. This is working successfully. The library is simple and effective.

After decoding the Wav ByteArray the method the library employs for playback is using the SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA event and then writing the mixed samples to the output stream.

```
player.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onSamplesCallback);
private function onSamplesCallback( evt : SampleDataEvent ):void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < samplesLength; i++) 
    {
        if(_mute ==  false){
           outputStream.writeFloat(samplesLeft[i]);
           outputStream.writeFloat(samplesRight[i]);
        }   
    }
}
```

My problem is that I need to silence this audio output immediately but whatever method I have tried there is a distinct (1 second approx) delay before the silence takes effect.

As you can see I've attempted to add a boolean to block any samples being written to the output stream but this has had no effect on the delay.

My suspicion is that this is a fundamental part of how the samples are buffered and then written out. Essentially by the time a user action on screen (clicking a mute button) has been called and the _mute boolean is set to true there are already samples waiting to be written to the output that cannot be affected.

Any advice or confirmation of my suspicion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
gfte.

Comment: Did either of these two answers help you out? If so, you should upvote using the up arrows next to the answer or mark one as the correct answer by clicking the green arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicion is probably right - but why stop it at that level? If you want to turn off the sound, would it not be better to set the volume on the soundTransform-property on the SoundChannel-object returned by the play method? (I assume the wav library returns this in some way)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have also tried this method however the same delay occurs unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the library you are using has a similar design to the native Flash Sound API wherein a SoundChannel object is returned from the play() method. This SoundChannel instance has a stop() method which should stop the sound right away.

```
var sound:WavSoundPlayer = new WavSoundPlayer();
var channel:WavSoundChannel = new WavSoundChannel();

sound.addEventListener( SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onSampleData );
channel = sound.play();

    private function onSamplesData( evt : SampleDataEvent ):void
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < samplesLength; i++) 
        {
           outputStream.writeFloat(samplesLeft[i]);
           outputStream.writeFloat(samplesRight[i]);   
        }
    }

    channel.stop()
```

The _mute variable in your example will only be able to change either before or after the loop, not while it is looping.

Comment: You're right about the design of the library. It does replicate the native Flash Sound API. However the stop function on the WavSoundChannel also has the exact same delay. This is what led me to believe that it might be something to do with a backlog of samples that have not been written to the output stream yet.

Comment: I've taken another look at the design of this library. IMO there are flaws that make it less flexible than it could be. To get the sound to stop right away, you could, inside WavSoundPlayer, make a reference to the SoundChannel object returned by the Sound.play() method called in configurePlayer(). Then when you call stop on the WavSoundPlayer, also call stop on the SoundChannel. Without calling stop on the SoundChannel instance you won't be able to stop the audio immediately.

Comment: Also, you should be able stop all audio happening in the FlashPlayer by calling flash.media.SoundMixer.stopAll().